# Could anyone help figure out this recursion 2.7 python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, factorial

a factorial of a positive integer n, written as n!, is defined as:

n*(n-1)*(n-2)*…*1
if n is 0 n! is defined as 1
if n is negative, n! is undefined

An example is:
12! = 12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1

Write a program that
1. Inputs a positive integer from the user.  If the integer is not positive, it displays an error message
2. Prompts the user to either have the factorial calculated by sequential programming (Option 1) or by recursion (Option 2)

Option 1:
using one of the top down iterative methods (e.g. while, for) find the factorial of any positive integer (including 0).

Option 2:
using recursion (see text section 6.3), find the factorial of any positive integer (including 0)

3. prints the factorial

Submit to this assignment a Word document (version 2010 or earlier) that contains the source code of your program and screen shots running it with both options and, for each option, with 0, 9, and -4

Hints:
you will need to define a function to perform this task using recursion
don’t try this with too large a number --- that may generate an error because of the memory it takes to perform

I seem to have figured out how to do the functions; however, I cannot seem to get them to work in the main() function.

When I run my program, the Menu() function executes; however, after I enter 1 or 2, my program returns

`(Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 59, in <module> main() File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 54, in main num = factorial() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'factorial' referenced before assignment)`

The following is what I have so far:

```
def Menu():
    print
    print ("For Sequential Programming Calculator, Enter 1")
    print ("For Recursion Calculator, Enter 2")
    print
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")
        if (choice >= 1) and (choice <=2) and (int(choice)==choice):
            return choice
        else:
            print ("Invalid Choice! Please enter 1 or 2")


def factorial():
    num = 1
    while n >= 1:
        num = num * n
        n = n - 1
    return num
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if num < 0:
        print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
    elif num == 0:
        print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
    else:
        print "The factorial of",num,"is",factorial(num)


def recur_factorial():
    if n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        factorial= n*recur_factorial(n-1)
    return factorial
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if num < 0:
       print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
    elif num == 0:
       print "The factorial of 0 is 1"
    else:
       print "The factorial of",num,"is",recur_factorial(num)


def main():
    print
    print("Factorial Calculator")
    print
    while True:
        choice = Menu()
        if choice == 1:
            num = factorial()
        elif choice == 2:
            factorial = recur_factorial()


main()
```

If anyone could help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having?  What does "cannot seem to get them to work"mean?

Comment: When I run my program, the Menu() function executes; however, after I enter 1 or 2, my program returns (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 54, in main
    num = factorial()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'factorial' referenced before assignment)

Comment: @BHR77 Change the variable name `factorial` in the line `factorial = recur_factorial()` to not match a function's name

Comment: thank you! now it's telling me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Prjct4", line 54, in main
    factorial(num)
NameError: global name 'num' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many bugs in your program.

However, the one that is first caused you a problem is that in your `main` code, you are assigning a value to a variable called factorial.  But factorial is supposed to be a function - as per your earlier definition.    Why are you assigning the result to a variable anyhow?   You don't do anything with it.  Maybe you mean `print factorial(num)`.

The next problem you encountered is that you have uninitialised variables all over the place.   I assume, from the traceback in your comment, that you changed the code in main to pass `num` into `factorial` - like `factorial(num)`.   But where do you expect `num` to get its value from?

You have some code (twice) that asks the user for a value for `num`, but it is in a place where it will never be executed - after the `return`s in your functions.

Perhaps you mean for this code to be in `main` before you call the factorial functions?

Comment: this is what i have now... Do you think you can help me?(check edit)

Comment: It seems that my answer answers your question - yay :)  You get one question per... question on Stack Overflow :)    The normal thing to do is to mark an answer as "accepted" when it has answered the question for you, and ask a new question if you have a new problem.    Otherwise it gets too confusing for everyone, if you keep editing the original question....  happy to help on the next question.   Remember to describe clearly what is going wrong for you.  Also, it will help you to chop your code down to the minimum code that makes the problem: that's what I did to find your first problem. GL.

Comment: By the way, it looks like your new program is working for the plain algorithm, but forgetting that the factorial of 0 is 1, not 0, `in recur_factorial`.   You can figure this out by putting `print "I'm returning that the factorial of", n , "is" < whatever you are returning>`, in both places that you return from `recur_factorial`.  You will see that at the bottom of the recursion, you return zero.  Zero times anything is zero.    This is only 1 of the two bugs in recur_factorial, but I'm sure you can find the other one with the same print statement.